# I need help here, how do I make the game continue with the and repeat?

Tags: python

Here is the script, as I said I want the game to continue if you have right and give another question but reapet the svar thing.

```
import random

LIST = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8, 9]
streak = 0
    
number1 = random.choice(LIST)
number2 = random.choice(LIST)
right = number1 * number2 
    
svar = float(input(str(number1) + " * " + str(number2)))
    
if svar == right:
    print("Right")
    streak = streak + 1
    print("Streak: " + str(streak))
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: Put the code in a loop.

Comment: Look into how [loops](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops) work.

Comment: Put all the code you want to repeat inside `while True:`

Comment: I tried adding a while true but that does just loop it but then the streak resets

Comment: Make sure `streak = 0` isn't inside the loop.

Comment: You could also just try searching ["\[python\] how to repeat"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+how+to+repeat) here on SO and get a bunch of related results.

Comment: ok that makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would change the Code to (depending what Python Version you use!):

```
# Python 3.x:
import random

LIST = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8, 9]
streak = 0
    
number1 = random.choice(LIST)
number2 = random.choice(LIST)
right = int(number1 * number2) 
print("Enter 0 to exit!")
svar = int(input(f"{number1} * {number2} is?    "))

while svar != 0:
    if svar == right:
        streak += 1
        print(f"Right!\nStreak: {streak}")
    else:
        print(f"Wrong!\nStreak ended @ {streak}")
        streak = 0
    number1 = random.choice(LIST)
    number2 = random.choice(LIST)
    right = int(number1 * number2)
    svar = int(input(f"{number1} * {number2} is?    "))
```

```
# Python 3.9:
import random

LIST = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8, 9]
streak = 0
    
number1 = random.choice(LIST)
number2 = random.choice(LIST)
right = int(number1 * number2) 
print("Enter 0 to exit!")

while (svar := int(input(f"{number1} * {number2} is?    "))) != 0:
    if svar == right:
        streak += 1
        print(f"Right!\nStreak: {streak}")
    else:
        print(f"Wrong!\nStreak ended @ {streak}")
        streak = 0
    number1 = random.choice(LIST)
    number2 = random.choice(LIST)
    right = int(number1 * number2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Put you `if - else` and what you want statements in a `while` loop

```py
while (condition):
      svar ...
      if ...
      else ...
```

Comment: Not just the `if else`. It should also have the code that picks the random numbers and displays the question.

Comment: What about `number1`, `number2`, and `right`?